# Trying to understand categories cofibered in groupoids

Tags: category-theory

In HTT, Lurie mentions that left fibrations are generalizations of categories cofibered in groupoids (and prop 2.1.1.3 gives some indication to this).

However, I'm not very familiar with categories cofibered in groupoids. I know that the dual notion, of categories fibered in groupoids are used to define stacks (which are useful in algebraic geometry-we can take quotients of schemes by group actions and get a stack). But what are categories cofibered in groupoids? Are there any examples? Do we get a dual notion of a "costack?"

Comment: The use of "co" here is unfortunate. A category cofibred in groupoids is a special kind of functor $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{B}$ – specifically, one such that $\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{B}^\mathrm{op}$ is a category fibred in groupoids. So in fact you already know everything about them.

Comment: ok, but why does lurie mention left fibrations and categories cofibered in groupoids? Why not go with right fibrations and categories fibered in groupoids?

Comment: It's an arbitrary choice. The theories are identical except for "handedness".